# Why does Tesco return T-mobile for this here-api query?

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Why does Tesco return T-mobile for this API query?  [https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=52.5344,-1.9948&limit=1&q=Tesco&apiKey={INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE}](https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=52.5344,-1.9948&limit=1&q=Tesco&apiKey=%7BINSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE%7D)

Response:

```
{"items":[{"title":"T-Mobile","id":"here:pds:place:826gcqdf-b4c4185edba2407f8ab7a5a3314c2d07","ontologyId":"here:cm:ontology:tesco","resultType":"place","address":{"label":"T-Mobile, West Bromwich, B70 8, United Kingdom","countryCode":"GBR","countryName":"United Kingdom","state":"England","countyCode":"WMD","county":"West Midlands","city":"West Bromwich","district":"West Bromwich","postalCode":"B70 8"},"position":{"lat":52.52075,"lng":-1.99064},"access":[{"lat":52.52111,"lng":-1.99158}],"distance":1547,"categories":[{"id":"600-6500-0073","name":"Mobile/Cell Phone Retailer","primary":true},{"id":"600-6500-0072","name":"Consumer Electronics Store"},{"id":"600-6500-0075","name":"Computer & Software"},{"id":"700-7100-0134","name":"Telephone Service"},{"id":"700-7200-0261","name":"IT and Office Equipment Services"},{"id":"700-7600-0116","name":"Gas Station"}],"chains":[{"id":"44"}],"contacts":[{"phone":[{"value":"+441215254794","categories":[{"id":"600-6500-0073"}]},{"value":"+443456102894"}],"www":[{"value":"http://www.t-mobile.co.uk","categories":[{"id":"600-6500-0073"}]},{"value":"http://www.youtube.com/lifesforsharing","categories":[{"id":"600-6500-0073"}]},{"value":"https://stores.tescomobile.com/west-midlands/west-bromwich/46-new-square?utm_source=extended_network&utm_medium=places&utm_campaign=WestBromwich_2335","categories":[{"id":"600-6500-0072"},{"id":"600-6500-0073"},{"id":"600-6500-0075"},{"id":"700-7100-0134"},{"id":"700-7200-0261"}]}],"email":[{"value":"Westbromwich@communityattesco.co.uk","categories":[{"id":"700-7600-0116"}]}]}],"openingHours":[{"categories":[{"id":"700-7600-0116"}],"text":["Mon-Sun: 00:00 - 23:59"],"isOpen":true,"structured":[{"start":"T000000","duration":"PT23H59M","recurrence":"FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU"}]},{"categories":[{"id":"600-6500-0073"},{"id":"700-7200-0261"},{"id":"600-6500-0075"},{"id":"700-7100-0134"},{"id":"600-6500-0072"}],"text":["Mon-Sat: 09:00 - 18:00","Sun: 10:00 - 16:00"],"isOpen":false,"structured":[{"start":"T090000","duration":"PT09H00M","recurrence":"FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"},{"start":"T100000","duration":"PT06H00M","recurrence":"FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:SU"}]}]}]}
{"mode":"full","isActive":false}
```

Comment: I think you will have to ask whoever maintains that API.

Comment: @JohnWu They only publish Stackoverflow with the tag `here-api` as the only public channel. Their slack is not publically accessible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks T-Mobile place has wrong "ontologyId":"here:cm:ontology:tesco".
Expected result is "ontologyId":"here:cm:ontology:t-mobile".
It's reported in Mapcreator tool and takes some times to fix.